# JSON Parsing --> Swift | Invalid top-level type in JSON write

Tags: php, json, swift

I am trying to retrieve information from a PHP file using Swift. I have seen online that I should use JSON parsing (I think it's called). So I searched and found some information online leading me to the following code:

```
func dataOfJson(urlString: String) -> NSArray{
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString);
    if (url != nil)
    {
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL);
        if (data != nil)
        {
            return try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data as Any) as AnyObject! as! NSArray;
        }else{
            //return "Error -> Data is nil!";
            return try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data as Any) as AnyObject! as! NSArray;
        }
    }else{
        return ["Error -> url is empty!"] as NSArray;
    }
}
```

I call the above function like so:`print(dataOfJson(urlString: "some url/test.php"));`

The URL I call has the following PHP code:

```
<?php   
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require "dbconnect.php";
global $connect;
$result = array();
$temp = array();

if ($connect){
    $fetch_data = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from dedi");

    while ( $row = $fetch_data->fetch_object() ){
        $temp = $row;
        array_push($result,$temp);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    return json_encode($result);
}
else{
    echo json_encode("Something went wrong");
    return json_encode("Something went wrong!");    
} 
mysqli_close(); ?>
```

Sadly, when I try and run the project, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix it, and yes, I have searched online and found resembling problems with solutions, but I could not understand these and some of the fixes just didn't change anything...

Comment: 1. MySQLi connection is never closed. 2. There is no need for `return json_encode(...);`. You should `exit()` instead. 3. You should use the appropriate `Content-Type` for JSON data, i.e. `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. 4. However, the source of the problem is most likely somewhere in the Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization#overview) states some requirements that the JSON from your PHP script probably doesn't always conform to:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,    NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Comment: My PHP seems to be alright, but I think the problem comes from swift... Is there anything wrong with my swift above?